# Generate list of employees

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a data structure like this :

```
data Person boss action = Person{
  salary  :: Float,
  subordonates :: [Person boss action],
  act :: action
  b :: boss
 }
```

And I want to create an organization starting with the president using this function :

```
create :: (boss -> [(action, boss)]) -- generator
       -> boss
       -> action
       -> Person boss action
```

The generator creates a list of employees. Each employee's boss is the current person who have called the function. I want to create a list of subordinates for each subordinate and so on (to infinity).

The problem is that I do not know how to:

- add the elements generated by the generator to the subordinates list of the current node
- do this recursively (an infinite number of times) for each of the subordinates. I thought about some sort of map but I don't get it.

Any advice || reference is highly appreciated !

Comment: `data Person action = Person { salary :: Float, subordinates :: [Person action], act :: action, b :: Maybe (Person action)}`.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code a little bit.

Comment: Type `Person` is similar to `Tree a` from `Data.Tree`.
Your function `create` is similar to `Data.Tree.unfoldTree`.
I suppose that the best way is reusing these.

Answer (score 5):

This is a more difficult problem than it looks. To see why, consider what type you will choose for `boss` when calling `create`. You say that each branch in the tree will create subordinates who have the parent node as their boss. So, clearly `boss` is not a free type variable in that function: it must be fixed as Person.

But how can you provide a Person object as the boss for each new person? There is a circular reference, because each person must know about its superior as well as all its subordinates at construction time. You cannot create the CEO until you have all subordinates already, but those cannot be created until you have their boss.

Now, this is not actually impossible: you can create circular data structures in Haskell without mutation, through the magic of laziness. But here there's no reason to, and the friction points out that the `boss` field in your Person struct is extraneous. Remove that, and the problem may be simplified to the point you can solve it.

---

It sounds like you are still having trouble getting started, so I'll provide some improved type signatures and a basic sketch of what your function might look like, with blanks for you to fill in.

```
type Salary = Float
data Position job = Position {salary :: Salary,
                              job :: job
                             }

data Person job = Person { position :: Position job,
                           subordinates :: [Person job]
                         }

-- the job type our positions will be parameterized by
data Management = CEO | Executive | Manager

create :: (Position job -> [Position job])
       -> Position job
       -> Person job
create f root = Person root (hireSubordinates root)
  where hireSubordinates boss = _

testHiringPlan :: Position Management -> [Position Management]
testHiringPlan (Position salary job) = case job of
  CEO -> [Position _ Executive | subordinateNum <- _]
  Executive -> [Position _ Manager | subordinateNum <- _]
  Manager -> [Position _ Manager | subordinateNum <- _]
```

As you can see I've separated the concerns of "what this person does" (their Position) and "who this person manages" (their subordinates). That way we can start from a Position, and from that generate the actual Person by creating a list of subordinates for them, avoiding any circular reference.

I've also provided an example type you might use for your `job` type variable, so that I could produce an example of what a generator passed to `create` might look like.

Comment: you are right. I used a different approach for the function.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put in the answer but I still have no clue how to create a function to add the persons that resulted from the generator to the current 'boss' 's list of subordinates and do the same thing for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the code given for the question, the `Person` data type includes a list of `Person` `subordinates` each of which contain a `boss` field that references the original `Person`.   A circular reference. Circular references are often unnecessarily complicated.

However, if you need to create a circular reference, it can be done inside a `let` statement

The example below is a trimmed down version of your example.  It retains the circular reference. In the `let` statement, the `Person` being created is defined in terms of `subordinates`.  The `subordinates` being generated by the generator function are defined in terms of `person`.

```
data Action = Manager | TeamLeader | Programmer deriving Show

data Person = Person {   subordinates :: [Person]
                       , act :: Action
                       , boss :: Maybe Person
                     } 

-- Generate the list of persons reporting to a boss
generate :: Person -> [Person]
generate boss = 
    case act boss of
        -- A programmer has no subordinates
        Programmer -> []  

        -- Team leaders and managers have subordinates
        TeamLeader -> replicate 2 $ create generate (Just boss)
        Manager -> replicate 3 $ create generate (Just boss)

-- Create a new person given that person's boss and a generator function
-- that generates the person's subordinates
create :: (Person -> [Person]) -> Maybe Person -> Person
create generator maybeBoss = 

    -- responsibility (action) depends on the boss's responsibility
    let action = case maybeBoss of
                     Nothing -> Manager
                     Just boss -> case act boss of
                                      Manager -> TeamLeader 
                                      TeamLeader -> Programmer

        -- note the circular reference happening on the next lines
        subordinates = generator person
        person = Person subordinates action maybeBoss

    in person

display :: Person -> IO ()
display (Person subordinates action boss ) = do
    putStrLn "" 
    putStrLn $ "person: " ++ show action 
    putStrLn $ "boss: " ++ show (fmap act boss)
    mapM_ display subordinates

main = display $ create generate Nothing
```